# Json object output of array to be displayed in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have json output from api wants to display in ng-repeat on div

```
[
        {
            "companyName": "abc",
            "namesList": [
                {
                    "name": "Jaakr1",
                    "email": "poonam.kumar@abc.com",
                    "job": "Developer 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "janam1",
                    "email": "raja@abc.com",
                    "job": "Developer 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I want to display like this

```
<div class="list-row">
            <div class="list-cell">abc</div>
            <div class="list-cell">Jaakr1</div>
            <div class="list-cell">poonam.kumar@abc.com</div>
            <div class="list-cell">Developer 1</div>
</div>
<div class="list-row">
        <div class="list-cell"></div>
        <div class="list-cell">janam1</div>
        <div class="list-cell">raja@abc.com</div>
        <div class="list-cell">Developer 2</div>
</div>
```

Please provide the solution

Comment: why not transorming that data to plain old array?

Comment: `Please provide the solution` Seriously ? Try something !

Comment: Check the answer i have posted that is pretty much generalized and works with multiple JSON objects inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from all the answers posted above i would like to post mine that will handle multiple JSON objects inside the array. Since you have only one object right now one of the above solution may work but when you have more that one object inside the array then this will work great.

HTML

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in data">
      <div class="list-row" ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in data[key1].namesList">
            <div class="list-cell"><span ng-if='$index == 0'>{{data[key1].companyName}}</span>                </div>
            <div class="list-cell">{{value2.name}}</div>
            <div class="list-cell">{{value2.email}}</div>
            <div class="list-cell">{{value2.job}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.data = [
        {
            "companyName": "abc",
            "namesList": [
                {
                    "name": "Jaakr1",
                    "email": "poonam.kumar@abc.com",
                    "job": "Developer 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "janam1",
                    "email": "raja@abc.com",
                    "job": "Developer 2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "companyName": "abc2",
            "namesList": [
                {
                    "name": "Jaakr12",
                    "email": "poonam.kumar@abc.com2",
                    "job": "Developer 12"
                },
                {
                    "name": "janam12",
                    "email": "raja@abc.com2",
                    "job": "Developer 22"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
})
```

For more generalization i have added two JSON objects inside the array and the output is exactly what you expected. To play around i have added the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/648/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngFor="let person of jsonObj.namesList">
    <div class="list-cell"></div>
    <div class="list-cell">{{ person.name }}</div>
    <div class="list-cell">{{ person.email }}</div>
    <div class="list-cell">{{ person.job}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in myArray[0].namesList" class="list-row">
        <div class="list-cell">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="list-cell">{{item.email}}</div>
        <div class="list-cell">{{item.job}}</div>
    </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('ReqWebApp', [])

myApp.controller('ReqAppController', function ReqAppController($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [
        {
            "companyName": "abc",
            "namesList": [
                {
                    "name": "Jaakr1",
                    "email": "poonam.kumar@abc.com",
                    "job": "Developer 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "janam1",
                    "email": "raja@abc.com",
                    "job": "Developer 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ReqWebApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Request</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ReqAppController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in myArray[0].namesList" class="list-row">
        <div class="list-cell">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="list-cell">{{item.email}}</div>
        <div class="list-cell">{{item.job}}</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="list-row" ng-repeat="nameObj in data.namesList">
        <div class="list-cell">{{data.companyName}}</div>
        <div class="list-cell">{{nameObj.name}}</div>
        <div class="list-cell">{{nameObj.email}}</div>
        <div class="list-cell"{{nameObj.job}}</div>
</div>
```